# CPU usage 1110% php-fpm7 listen queue issue

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, cpu-usage

I have been facing a weird issue lately. I'm running a WordPress blog on LEMP stack on DigitalOcean droplet 48GB RAM, 12vCPUs, 960GB SSD.

The website is a local news site and gets around 5-6 million pageviews per month.

Cloudflare 'cache-all' is enabled and hence the site loads instantly from  Cloudflare Edge cache for everyone. It's blazing fast. Hence, there isn't much stress on the backend server.

But even with a decent VPS, still my CPU usage is 1100% (as shown by New Relic), `top` shows

```
load average: 18.66, 18.64, 18.52
```

`htop` shows all 12 CPU cores working at ~100% capacity. Surprisingly memory usage is normal, it's just 10GB out of 48GB.

I can see that all CPU is consumed by php-fpm processes:

```
PID   USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
19210 www-data  20   0 1520432  90032  49060 R  77.1  0.2   0:59.80 php-fpm7.0
19029 www-data  20   0 1445340  86236  44768 R  70.4  0.2   1:46.98 php-fpm7.0
19212 www-data  20   0 1444336  82176  41644 R  70.1  0.2   0:55.79 php-fpm7.0
18984 www-data  20   0 1444600  82612  41644 R  69.8  0.2   2:16.31 php-fpm7.0
19199 www-data  20   0 1446608  84436  41516 R  69.8  0.2   1:11.39 php-fpm7.0
19296 www-data  20   0 1520180  89428  48932 R  68.1  0.2   0:28.09 php-fpm7.0
19190 www-data  20   0 1444616  82608  41708 R  64.1  0.2   1:13.03 php-fpm7.0
19197 www-data  20   0 1520364  90052  49188 R  61.5  0.2   1:12.38 php-fpm7.0
18991 www-data  20   0 1444488  84448  43564 R  60.5  0.2   2:06.25 php-fpm7.0
19202 www-data  20   0 1520444  90172  49188 R  59.5  0.2   1:10.30 php-fpm7.0
19251 www-data  20   0 1444372  81444  41388 R  59.5  0.2   0:43.51 php-fpm7.0
19113 www-data  20   0 1520436  89908  49060 R  59.1  0.2   1:14.23 php-fpm7.0
19250 www-data  20   0 1444320  82104  41516 R  57.5  0.2   0:46.95 php-fpm7.0
19076 www-data  20   0 1442900  80768  41388 R  56.8  0.2   1:20.53 php-fpm7.0
19252 www-data  20   0 1520292  89712  48932 R  56.5  0.2   0:43.56 php-fpm7.0
18948 www-data  20   0 1520468  90856  49828 R  55.5  0.2   2:21.88 php-fpm7.0
19200 www-data  20   0 1443004  80828  41392 R  54.8  0.2   1:09.20 php-fpm7.0
19074 www-data  20   0 1444452  82268  41516 R  53.8  0.2   1:18.03 php-fpm7.0
```

So I checked logs, checked settings, tried to play around with pm.settings, but nothing helped. Then I looked at php-fpm status page and something is strange. It shows

```
pool    www
process manager static
start time  16/Jul/2020:18:47:09 +0000
start since 37990
accepted conn   5730391
listen queue    515
max listen queue    574
listen queue len    65536
idle processes  0
active processes    57
total processes 57
max active processes    109
max children reached    0
slow requests   2
```

My pm settings are

```
listen.backlog = 65536
pm = static
pm.max_children = 18
pm.start_servers = 15
pm.min_spare_servers = 10
pm.max_spare_servers = 15
pm.max_requests = 900
request_terminate_timeout = 60
request_slowlog_timeout = 10
slowlog = /var/log/php/7.0/slow.$pool.log
```

If I increase the pm.max_children from 18 to 50, the Load Average shoots up from 18 to around 55. Usually more php-fpm processes means more memory usage, but my processes use very less memory and are unusually high CPU usage.

I see that `listen queue = 500+` in the status page. And I doubt that my nginx or php-fpm is not configured properly, some small setting is limiting it.

Also, the script that all these processes are apparently running is: `/var/www/domain.com/htdocs/index.php`

Surprisingly, New Relic shows nothing. It says server response time is 247ms, and the app-server score is green (best rating) while under infrastructure, it shows CPU usage 1100%!

I have been debugging it since two days and have hit a wall. Please guide me.

Comment: I, myself, is just novice. However, you are using `pm=static` but these settings `pm.start_servers = 15`, `pm.min_spare_servers = 10`, `pm.max_spare_servers = 15` are for `pm=dynamic`. Also kindly read this also. https://medium.com/@sbuckpesch/apache2-and-php-fpm-performance-optimization-step-by-step-guide-1bfecf161534

Comment: Thank you. you're right...those settings won't be used for `static`, I was tweaking around with `dynamic` and `ondemand` too, hence the settings remain. For `static` only `pm.max_children` is used, which is very low (18) as of now.

Comment: Did you find solution...?

Comment: Have not found a solution yet. Still looking :(